# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Xaml is not loading (vs2008), it errors, how to re-register?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, xaml

recently got an issue when loading vs 2008, it displays this... can anyone tell me how to reregister the file... or something..

I don't wish to reinstall the vs 2008 again....

The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Xaml ({E58C2A8B-BCC4-4559-AD59-D62EB6D58A22}) did not load because of previous errors. For assistance, contact the package vendor. To attempt to load this package again, type 'devenv /resetskippkgs' at the command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `devenv.exe /setup` on a (elevated) command prompt. I don't know if it fixes your error, but it seems to fix a lot of things.

What happens if you do what the error message suggests, i.e. call `devenv /resetskippkgs`?

Other than that, instead of reinstalling, try the repair option of the setup, which fixes many errors.

Comment: repair setup worked... strange! thanks... i thought i remember reading you had to re-registert the file in the registry.. but this was much easier..

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to do exactly as the error message says.  Enable the loading of skipped packages by running "devenv /resetskippkgs" from the command line.  This will *likely* fix the problem.

If it does not, then I would repair the Visual Studio installation via Add / Remove Programs menu.  This fixes most issues that cause the XAML designer to fail to load.

If you do a repair you **must** do the resetskippkgs above command because.  There is a bug in repair such that it will not cause suppressed packages to start loading again (fixed in VS2010).

Answer (score 0):

don't relly need to reset anything, if you don't have Visual Studio SP1 installed, you should install it.. that fixed the problem for me :D