# Visual Studio 2008 WPF Problems

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

So I'm trying to learn WPF and my home and school setup in Visual Studio is totally different. I have no controls, no properties, no intellisense on the XAML page on my home computer.

I looked around for this problem and I saw something with regedit, and I have the correct info there...still nothing though. Here are two print screens so you can see what I'm talking about.

[Home Computer](http://picasaweb.google.com/rmk5056/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCO_ytqn_zL22QA#5384067406701024802)
[School Computer](http://picasaweb.google.com/rmk5056/DropBox?authkey=Gv1sRgCO_ytqn_zL22QA#5384066478885655058)

Clearly, the school computer will be a lot easier to learn on...but most of my learning and coding will be done outside of school.

**Edit 1**

When trying to run devenv /resetskippkgs I get the following error:

> Package Load Failure
>
> Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Xaml' has failed to load properly (GUID = xxxx). Please contact package vendor for assitance. Apllication restart is recommended due to possible environment corruption. Would you like to disable loading this package in the future? You may use 'devenv /resetskippkgs' to re-enable package loading.

Comment: I would re-install visual studio on your home computer and make sure you got .net 3.0 at least. I've never encountered this problem before.

Comment: Also try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074709/microsoft-visualstudio-xaml-is-not-loading-vs2008-it-errors-how-to-re-registe It's not the exact same problem but it might work.

Comment: I just tried loading the project thru the devenv /resetsskippkgs command. Got the error that is in my first edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Pack 1 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be your solution - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vswpfdesigner/thread/88bc758f-e190-440a-a244-709ca646bc77

Comment: As I have said in the question...I have the correct information in the regedit.